# Ant search in text file some text expression

Tags: eclipse, ant, expression

Ant search in text file some text expression, if it **NOT** found I try to delete file that **txt**  was. So my code  in Ant is down, but I don't know how put **NOT** correctly

> ```
>       <target name="ifDelete">     
>     <if>
>         <length when="greater" length="0">
>             <fileset file="MyText.txt">
>                 <!--containsregexp negate="true"-->
>                     <containsregexp expression="findME" />
>                 <!--/containsregexp-->
>             </fileset>
>         </length>
>         <then>
>             <delete includeemptydirs="true">
>                 <fileset dir="FileIgonnaDelete">
>                 </fileset>
>             </delete>
>         </then>
>     </if>
> </target>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To search and delete - means seek and destroy - files in a fileset that do not contain a specific text, use something like :

```
<delete verbose="true">
 <fileset dir="rootdir/to/search" includes="**/*.txt">
  <not>
   <contains text="findMe"/>
  </not>
 </fileset>
</delete>
```

you may use one or more nested resource collections (fileset, dirset ...) within delete.
see Ant manual [delete](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html), [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) and [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) for details.

Comment: I found the ans .Instead _length when="**greater**" length="0"_  have to be  _length when="**equal**" length="0"_. And that do exactly what I need.